# I'm getting data consuming error with Flume Kafka Source in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, flume, consumer

We have a Kafka cluster currently running. An application of ours is retrieving data from a Topic in this Kafka cluster using Flume Kafka Source. Our Kafka Cluster is running on servers. Our Flume application is running on a Docker Container.

Now we want to migrate our Flume application running on Docker to Kubernetes environment. When we did this, we encountered some errors. We detected that the Flume Kafka Source was unable to retrieve the data.

Flume logs about errors are as follows. (I replaced some special parts with ...)

```
[PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.processDisconnection:671)  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test1] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.markCoordinatorUnknown:729)  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=...] Group coordinator ...:9092 (id: ... rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
```

Why did we get an error in a Kubernetes environment when we did not encounter any problems while working on Docker?

Thank you!

Comment: You're getting network errors because kubernetes has its own networking setup. You shouldn't expect a docker network bridge to work the same way

Comment: @OneCricketeer So how can I solve this problem? I am trying to reach Kafka Cluster on another server from pod. Can you give some advice for network settings?

Comment: Well, I don't know how your cluster is setup, or how you're running Kafka, but CoreDNS is the default provider and so connecting to something like `kafka namespace.svc.cluster.local` would just be a Service/Pod address, rather than just `kafka` like in Docker. However, each pod needs to advertise itself on unique names for clients to communicate... I generally recommend people use Strimzi in Kubernetes and it discusses how internal services can communicate with it https://strimzi.io/